# Xml Serialization of a List where the parent element has additional elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

How would this be achieved in C# xml serializable class(s)?

```
<Category Attrib1="Value1" Attrib2="Value2">
  <Item>Item1</Item>
  <Item>Item2</Item>
  <Item>Item3</Item>
  <Item>Item4</Item>
</Category>
```

Inheriting Category from `List<Item>` results in the two Category properties being ignored by the xml serializer.  If Category is composed of a `List<Item>` property a parent element is added around all the Item's (e.g. Category\Items\Item).  Both are undesirable.  The Xml must look like the example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Category
{       
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Attrib1 { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Attrib2 { get; set; }     

    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Tested and works fine.